# Android - XML Custom shape

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I'm trying to get this shape done in xml:
[image: Shape]

*What I have tried:*

```
 <item>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/res_pressed"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/res_default"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp"
            android:left="15dp"/>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Still I can't get it right with round and straight corners for the yellow shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `shape` drawable so you can add a corners tag.  Try

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/res_pressed" />
            <corners android:topLeft="10dp" android:bottomLeft="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="15dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/res_default" />
            <corners android:topRight="10dp" android:bottomRight="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Tried and it gives the same result with question with Android 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround:

Create `top.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp"/>
 </shape>
```

Create `bot.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

The desired shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bot" />
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/top"
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, identical to `Gabe Sechan` post but with few modifications..

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```